# Remove all localnotifications and Cell in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilocalnotification

I'm looking for a way to delete all the `localNotifications` in my tableView, with a button.
I've tried with playing with the `cancelAllNotifications` and `[array removeAllObject];` but that didn't work out. 
I do have the slide to delete function one bye one working.

Importend to know is that every every section has 2 rows of `localNotifications`, as seen below.

**cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    int rowIndex = (indexPath.section*2) + indexPath.row;

    // Get list of local notifications
    NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:rowIndex];

    // Display notification info
    [cell.textLabel setText:[localNotification.alertAction description]];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    return cell;
```

**canEditRowAtIndexPath**

```
    return YES;      
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

**commitEditingStyle:**

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        int rowIndex = (indexPath.section*2); //get the 2 items of the section
        NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  scheduledLocalNotifications];

        UILocalNotification *notify = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notify];
        notify = [localNotifications objectAtIndex:rowIndex+1];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notify];

        [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

Anyone has an idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you reloaded the table view after removing all objects from the data source array?

You should do this in your button's action

```
- (void)clearAllButtonTapped:(UIButton *)clearAllButton
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    [theDataArray removeAllObjects];
    [theTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I've reloaded the table view: `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the `canEditRowAtIndexPath` method. The problem now is that I can't set the array in the removeAllObjects, even if I declare the notifications array in the .h file.

Comment: It not a good way to reload the table view in `canEditRowAtIndexPath`, the method is designed just to know whether a row can be edit or not. Do other things may lead to some potential problem.

Comment: And I'm not quite sure about `I can't set the array in the removeAllObjects`. Do you mean you want to add some new local notifications after remove all existing ones? If so, you should use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification]`. Simply add to the array shouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation. After I press the button the array of `localNotifications`, called localnotifications, must be empty right? The thing is, as you can see in the code, the Array localnotifications is made in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and in the commitEditingStyle. So I can't get it in your void method.

Comment: Then you don't need to `removeAllObjects`. Since you fetch the `localNotifications` array (from `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  scheduledLocalNotifications]`) every time you need. After you `cancelAllLocalNotifications`, the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  scheduledLocalNotifications]` method will return nil (or an empty array? i'm not sure) automatically.

Comment: Thanks LouisZhu! That did the trick :) Only it wont clear realtime, I first have to go back in the `NavigationController`. Is there a solution for?

Comment: Do you mean the `cancelAllLocalNotifications` method? But i don't think so. I wrote codes to test this: `NSLog(@"before: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    NSLog(@"after: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]);
`. The `before` line prints 2 notifications I scheduled, and the `after` line prints an empty array.

Comment: Yes! I tested also this way, the Log statement shows the realtime values, but the cells are not empty when I press the button. I first have to do a handeling like, press the back button in the `navigationController`.